# Crash when loading image Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

When loading the main view controller of my app it loads multiple images. Using the `sd_setImage(with: reference)` method. It has worked forever and now I am suddenly getting crashes with the exception

> -[SDImageCache storeImage:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000c60380
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDImageCache storeImage:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000c60380'

The stacktrace isn't showing a line in my code that's causing the problem. Is this an internal Firebase bug? How do I fix it?

Comment: You can try to delete the derived data and then rebuild

Comment: Tried prior. No cigar

Comment: Are you using 2.0.1 or higher of FirebaseStorageUI?

Comment: I am using the following related dependencies
Using Firebase (3.15.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.7.0)
Using FirebaseAuth (3.1.1)
Using FirebaseCore (3.5.2)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.1.2)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.9)
Using FirebaseStorage (1.1.0)
Using FirebaseUI (0.7.0)
Using SDWebImage (4.0.0)

Answer (score -1):

Firebase calls continuous asynchronous calls to the observer.  You should always check for `nil` or `NSNull` before attempting to present data from the database.  You may have a higher resolution image that takes longer to load than it does your view to appear.

Comment: Worked earlier and is valid according to the Firebase documentation here under "Downloading Images with FirebaseUI" https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files